# Show input only after button press

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to hide the `<input>` from the home page, I only want the input to display when I press the button.

I was making a typing game. I added an input field for mobile users, but I only want it to show if the button is clicked.

Comment: Please add the relevant code to the question, not a link to GitHub...

Comment: Also using we do not use phrases like "please help" here. Thats what the site is all about. Using " I need help urgently" also gives you no extra attention. The site is run by volunteers. They help if they are interested when ever they have time and want to actually help. Askign a quality question that meats the guidelines is certainly more helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

As I could see input fields are not hidden, so may want to hide them first. Example style="display:none". Then in your onclick add something like the following:

```
$("#buttonid").on("click", function(){
 $("#inputid").show();
```

Comment: Thanks , I will try this later in the day!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the ID of the button and the input, you can do the following:

```
const button = document.querySelector("#button")
const input = document.querySelector("#input");

button.addEventListener("click", () => input.style.display = "block");
```

Please note that the input should be with a `display: none;` CSS property first.

Comment: You should avoid to use `.style` function in JS in 2021. The modern approach is to use `.classList` +
 `.add('class-name')` , `.remove('class-name')` or `.toggle('class-name')` to apply changes through CSS.
 This causes far less issues incl. possible specificity weight issues.

Comment: Thanks , I will try this later in the day!

Answer (score 0):

In html you need to have an `<input>` and `<button>`.

```html
<input type="text" name="info" id="info" class="">
<button id="showInfo">Show Input</button>
```

In css add class `.active` and set on input `display: none`.

```css
input {
   display: none;
}

.active {
   display: block;
}
```

First set is download from DOM `<input>` and `<div>`.
The second step is add `event listener` for click event on the `<button>`.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input#info');
const showInput = document.querySelector('button#showInfo');

showInput.addEventListener('click', () => {
   input.classList.toggle('active')
})
```

Comment: Thanks , I will try this later in the day!